# Failing to build Android application with ant

Tags: android, ant

I am getting this error when I type ant in the command prompt

`C:\Mobility Android\Mobility\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145
\bin\build.xml:90: Cannot find D:\android-sdk-windows\tools/tools/ant/build.xml
imported from C:\Mobility Android\Mobility\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.
v20100518-1145\bin\build.xml`

Comment: is your android-sdk really at D:\android-sdk-windows?

Comment: yup..it is at D:\android-sdk-windows location

Answer (score 1):

The path `D:\android-sdk-windows\tools/tools/ant/build.xml` has two copies of `tools` in it. It should only have one. Perhaps it's a problem in your `local.properties` file?